# How can I access a correct version of a Java Desktop class

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX application that can be used to edit files of a particular type on Windows OS.
By using launch4j-maven-plugin I can make an exe file, and by using Inno Setup I can make an installer of this application that has a particular file type associated to it (kb files).
If I install the application and double click on the file that this application is associated to while the application is not open already, the application opens and I can read the said file (I read main function args and use the filename to read the file).
The problem I have is if the user tries to double click the file that this application is associated to, while the application is running.
That does not work.
At another answers I found out that by using Desktop.setOpenFileHandler(...) I can set the open file handler that will handle this event.
However, my version of Desktop does not have this option, it only has options to open, edit, print, mail or browse a file as can be seen from the allowed actions that are part of the Desktop class that I can access:

```
    public static enum Action {
        /**
         * Represents an "open" action.
         * @see Desktop#open(java.io.File)
         */
        OPEN,
        /**
         * Represents an "edit" action.
         * @see Desktop#edit(java.io.File)
         */
        EDIT,
        /**
         * Represents a "print" action.
         * @see Desktop#print(java.io.File)
         */
        PRINT,
        /**
         * Represents a "mail" action.
         * @see Desktop#mail()
         * @see Desktop#mail(java.net.URI)
         */
        MAIL,
        /**
         * Represents a "browse" action.
         * @see Desktop#browse(java.net.URI)
         */
        BROWSE
    };
```

So my question is how can I get to the correct version of a Desktop class (my jre is jre 1.8.0_351).
And if that is not possible, can anyone propose another method for handling the event of opening a file by double clicking on it in Windows?

I first had Java 1.8.0_202, I updated to 1.8.0_351 to try to solve the problem, but that did not help.
I also tried to use the Application class to set event handler:

```
 Application lowLevelApp = Application.GetApplication();
 MyEventHandler eventhandler = new MyEventHandler(lowLevelApp);
 eventhandler.setOpenFilesHandler(new MyHandleOpenFilesEvent());
 lowLevelApp.setEventHandler(eventhandler);
```

but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking at the documentation of that method
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/desktop/OpenFilesHandler.html
you would see that this method was introduced in version 9 of Java. At the moment we are at version 19 so it is quite likely that some API between your 8 und the current 19 have changed. Just upgrade your Java and JavaFX and everything will be good.

Comment: I will label this as a proper answer to this question. However, we cannot update our JavaFX component at this moment. It is too complex and uses specific features available only before Java 9. I will just repost the question to specifically target Java 1.8.

Comment: I am not aware of ANY features which would not be available even in latest version of JavaFX. Could you name them here please?

Comment: Sure, these are some imports that I see fail when I switch to Java 18:
    import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.KeyBinding;
    import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase;
    import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText;
    import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow;
    import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl;
    import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin;

Comment: Ok, but I would not call that a missing feature. What you have cited is non-public API and if you use that you are fully on your own. This link https://stackoverflow.com/a/69458209/4262407 may be of interest to you.